# If else statement with else part not working

Tags: jquery

I am writing a if/else statement that includes css in it. The if part works but the else part does not. What am I doing wrong, can someone guide me thanks?!

This is my statement.

---

```
if(!$(#ron.val()){
   $("#ron_lan").attr("disabled",true).css({"opacity":0.3});
}
else{
   alert('else');
   $("select#ron_lan").attr("disabled",false).css({"opacity":1});    
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: i don't think i'm using any IDE...i'm just doing this on eclipse with apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the value of `#ron` is. If it is an input the possible values are text, empty or spaces.

For example:

```
!""             // Negating an empty string gives you TRUE
!" "            // Negating a space gievs you FALSE
!"any text 123" // Negating any text gives you FALSE
!undefined      // Negating undefined gives you TRUE, read on...
```

It can also depend on the existance of `#ron`. If the element with id `#ron` does not exist, or does not have a "value" property (is not an input). jQuery will always return `undefined` which could explain why `!undefined` will always return true and your `else` path is never reached.

**Recap:**

1. Check if `#ron` exists on the html  eg. `$('#ron').length` should return 1
2. Check that `#ron` is an input or textarea so that `$('#ron').val()` wont return `undefined`
3. Check the values in the textarea and trim it to avoid spaces vs empty string scenarios

Answer (score 5):

`$(#ron.val()` is invalid and will always be false. It should be

`$('#ron').val()`

Notice the brackets and quotes. `#ron` is the selector in this case.

Also, don't use `attr('disabled', false)`. You should just remove the attribute entirely with `removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: sorry had a mistake in typying...i do have it like you mentioned. $(!("#ron").val())   still not working

Comment: Care with that syntax, it should be `if( !$("#ron").val() )...`. @ron

Comment: thanks! Still the else part is not getting triggered.